# Java runtime exec getting error for String array

Tags: java, runtime

I am trying to execute commands with the Runtime exec() method
I have created one common utility method

```
public static Process exec(String[] path) throws IOException {  
    return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(path); 
}
```

and I am calling this method as

```
 Process p = ProcessBuilderUtils.exec(new String[] {
                    "\""+ffmpegCommand +"\"", 
                    " -i ", 
                    "\""+filename+"\""
 });
```

and I am getting file not found error. is there any alternative or any other ways to pass array in exec() method.

Comment: Your code is telling Java to execute a command whose name has quotes  in it.  No command exists with that name, hence the "file not found" error message.

Comment: Share the specifics. how are you calling the method? which command you are trying to execute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is telling Java to execute a command whose name has quotes in it. No command exists with that name, hence the "file not found" error message.

The code should probably be:

```
Process p = ProcessBuilderUtils.exec(new String[] {
                ffmpegCommand, 
                "-i", 
                filename});
```